# ASP.NET and AJAX - CalendarExtender isn't working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendarextender

Brand new to AJAX. I want to add it to Visual Studio (2015 version).

I downloaded AJAX and added the .dll file to my Bin in my web app. Then I went into my Toolbox and added a new tab for this .dll file.

Then I added this to my web.config:

```
 <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit"
                   namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
                   assembly="AjaxControlToolKit"/>
      </controls>
```

I added this to my master page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
```

I have this on a webform page (and a page using my master page template):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtRegStart" runat="server" CssClass="formtextbox"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CalendarExtender ID="TxtRegStart_CalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="TxtRegStart"></asp:CalendarExtender>
```

The CalendarExtender doesn't do anything... why? (Clicking in the textbox doesn't pull up a calendar.) What did I forget to do?

**UPDATE**

I got it to work. I had to change my code on my master page from this `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />` to this:

```
<ajaxtoolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true" ID="ScriptManager1" ScriptMode="Debug" CombineScripts="false" />
```

Comment: FYI, ToolkitScriptManager is now deprecated.

Comment: What should I be using instead? Sorry, very new to this.

Comment: Sorry, should have provided more info. ToolkitScriptManager is now deprecated and ScriptManager preferred. But you'll probably need to upgrade your toolkit version (probably via the nuget package manager?)

Comment: Okay thanks, I had no idea there was a difference between the two, lol. I'll have to research it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing the problem is because you are writing

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ....>
```

instead, try this

```
<ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender ....>
```

because you define the `TagPrefix` was `ajaxtoolkit` here:

```
<controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit"
         namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
         assembly="AjaxControlToolKit"/>
</controls>
```

Comment: Okay I tried that and still same issue. I will def use the code you gave though cause I do see that was one of my mistakes. I am still missing something else though.

Comment: I figured it out... I had to change my code to this:  `<ajaxtoolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
        EnableScriptLocalization="true" ID="ScriptManager1" ScriptMode="Debug" CombineScripts="false" />` instead of `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />` and now it works